# Groovy - parse stringified JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I have a stringified json looking like this:

```
{u'a': u'1', u'b': 2, u'c': 3 }
```

Which I am trying to parse as a JSON object.

I have tried using `JsonSlurper` with the following code:

```
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(param)

    object.a
```

But it failed because of the `u`:

```
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'u' with an int value of 117

The current character read is 'u' with an int value of 117
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'u' with an int value of 117
line number 1
index number 1
{a': u'1', u'b': 2, u'c': 3}
```

How can I parse this string?

Many thanks

Comment: That's not JSON, _"stringified"_ or otherwise.  Why do you have `u` prefixing the keys?  Why are the keys not in double quotes?  Why are the string values not in double quotes?  A JSON representation of what you have would be: `{"a": "1", "b": 2, "c": 3 }`

Comment: ok but is there any clean way to clean this then? I tried using this `param.replaceAll('u\'', '\'')` but if fails because of the single quotes

Comment: Where does it come from? You're often better cleaning upstream (the thing seeing this to you) rather than making your code handle all sorts of crazy edge cases

Comment: @Spearfisher, JsonSlurper should parse your stringified, if after replacing **u'** to **'** you replace all single quotes with **double quotes**. It's dirty, but should help.

Answer (score 0):

So this looks like valid Python, not JSON. Assuming you control the Python program that has passed you the data, do something like the following in that program:

```
import json
json.dumps( {u'a': u'1', u'b': 2, u'c': 3 } )
```

if you don't control the Python, if you're calling your Groovy script from a bash pipeline, can you add the following step to your pipeline?

```
echo "{u'a': u'1', u'b': 2, u'c': 3 }" | python -c "import json, sys, fileinput; print json.dumps( eval( (open(sys.argv[1] ) if sys.argv[1:] else sys.stdin).read())) "
```

In last case you could call that line of Python from Groovy...